# The best way to fix a deteriorating foundation?

Tags: concrete, foundation

I've got a corner of my foundation that is crumbling. I tried concrete vinyl patching but it only lasted few years and got worse. Here is what I used before:
[image]

I am not sure what else to use, other than straight Quickrete.

I can't seem to find any information on how to fill gaping holes like this. The only thing I found is how to fix small cracks or small depth holes.

Home was built in 2015 in Houston.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm that doesn't look like the concrete I'm used to, but the concrete repair guys I've talked to used a sticky high strength concrete for patching.  It's not particularly hard if you can find out the suitable mix.  If you can bare the top of it  you can also pour it, but with either method first you have to chip away the flawed concrete until you're down to something good to bond with.

Comment: I updated the pic. It was misleading before since it was a picture of the patching material that was used and not the concrete.

Comment: Do you have a water/moisture problem on the slab at that corner? Is this a basement wall?

Comment: The foundation is crumbling on a house less than 10 years old? Care to name & shame the contractor? Other Houstonians (or those about to be) might appreciate knowing who to _avoid_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That corner looks like it was screwed up from the start with the way that bottom corner brick was laid. I would be drilling a number of holes in that bottom brick's mortar and removing it. Scrape away all that patch stuff from the slab.Then hammer away at that corner to break away any weak concrete. Then I'd get some 2x4's or 2x6's and re-frame that corner level with the existing slab and support the framing with a a few stakes/rebar. Drill and screw in a few Tapcons to act as mesh/rebar. Mix up some real concrete and re pour that corner. After it hardens, get some mortar and install that last brick correctly. Fill in any other voids in the brick mortar. This is a bit more work that you were probably hoping for but this is what I've done up North where they have harsh winters and it holds up real good.

Comment: Thanks Jack. That sounds like it would be a good way to fix and reinforce the fill. However, this is probably above my skill level. I should get a foundation shop to fix this. What do you estimate a repair like this would cost?

Comment: Everyone of us has probably said that at least a dozen times in our careers. Honestly though, I have no idea what a contractor would charge for this. Maybe look for a handyman and assist him in the work.

Comment: thanks @JACK I did some thinking on this and it shouldn't be too difficult to fix. Question: (1) what size tapcons would you use and how many? (2) how viscous is quikrete 5000 psi? Here are the steps I am thinking [1] clean out all loose materials
[2] apply paint cement (Portland cement + water)
[3] wait 24 hours for cement paint to cure [4] apply Quickrete 5000 PSI
[5] tape a piece of plastic around repair to keep concrete from drying out [6] put some type of frame around it to hold concrete in

Comment: One or two Tapcons 1 1/2" set 3/4" into slab  depending on how much you chip away. Quikrete is firm when mixed, I'd use general Sakrete, it's a bit more fluid. Don't get a fast setting mix. Don't use cement paint, the new cement needs to bond with old cement. Depending on how much you knock out, you might need the frame put in first.

Comment: @amrog if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to an answer that helps you. It's also appropriate to click the check mark next to the answer that helps you the _most_.

Comment: Got it, just did, thanks for the reminder.